# Does this javascript do anything?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to track down some javascript that is running when an anchor tag is clicked.  Using Firebug I found this code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;">
   ...
</a>
```

What, if anything would `href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;"` do here?

This is an abbreviated version of the code, if you'd like to see the full version let me know and I can throw it up.  It didn't appear relevant to the question but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there will be an event listener waiting for this link to be clicked.

and that `return false` prevents the browser from executing the redirect

Comment: interesting, any suggestions on how to find the event listener?

Comment: @Abe Miessler this is just wild guessing right now, but i suppose the <a> is in some kind of container element. look for the ID's and CLASSES of those. then scan the loaded javascript for those id's and classe's and you might find something like 'addEventListener'.. depends on js library

Answer (score 0):

Well the return false prevents the link from doing anything, so if the href was url, the link would not take you there, it wouldn't do anything.

I don't think `javascript:;` will do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It cancels the click event normally attached to a `a` tag